How to prove this equation in quantum information theory?
I‘ve just started studying quantum information theory and encounter this equation in this paper Stabilizer Renyi Entropy.
$$
\sum_{P\in \mathcal{P}_n}\Xi_P(|\psi\rangle)={\rm tr}|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|^2=1\tag{1}
$$
$\mathcal{P}_n$ is the group containing all $n$-qubit Pauli strings with phase $+1$, and $\Xi_P(|\psi\rangle)$ is defined as
$$
\Xi_P(|\psi\rangle)=d^{-1}\langle\psi|P|\psi\rangle^2
$$
where $d=2^n$ is the dimension of the Hilbert space. $|\psi\rangle$ is an arbitrary quantum state.
For $|\psi\rangle$ as any computational basis, it can be easily proved that $(1)$ is true. But for $|\psi\rangle$ as an arbitrary state, I don't know how to prove it. I tried to insert some  identity operators, but it didn't work.
Can anyone give me some hints?

What does "with phase +1" mean?

@Norbert Schuch The number in front of the Pauli string is $+1$. For example, $\mathcal{P}_3$ is composed of operators like $X\otimes Y\otimes I$, but not $-X\otimes Y\otimes I$ or $-iX\otimes Y \otimes I$.

I think there's one more thing I need to clarify. $\mathcal{P}_n$ is a group in the sense that $\mathcal{P}_n=\tilde{\mathcal{P}}_n/\left<\pm i \mathbb{I}\right>$, where $\tilde{\mathcal{P}}_n$ is the group of all $n$-qubit Pauli strings with phase $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$, and $\mathbb{I}$ is the identity element of $\tilde{\mathcal{P}}_n$.

First, note that you can write
\begin{align}
\sum_{P\in \mathcal{P}_n}\Xi_P(|\psi\rangle)
&=
\frac{1}{d}\sum_{P\in \mathcal{P}_n}\langle\psi\otimes\psi\rvert
P\otimes P\lvert \psi\otimes\psi\rangle\\
&=
\langle\psi\otimes\psi\rvert
\Big[ \frac{1}{d}\sum_{P\in \mathcal{P}_n}
P\otimes P\Big]
\lvert \psi\otimes\psi\rangle
\ .
\end{align}
Now consider the term in the bracket -- first for one qubit, $P\in P_1$. Then, we have that
$$
\Big[ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{P\in \mathcal{P}_1}
P\otimes P\Big]
= \frac{1}{2}\big[I\otimes I + X\otimes X + Y\otimes Y + Z\otimes Z]
= \mathbb F \ ,
$$
which is precisely the SWAP operator $\mathbb F$ ("flip") which swaps the two systems. Since the sum over the individual components in the tensor product factors, the same holds for the $n$-qubit system,
$$
\Big[ \frac{1}{d}\sum_{P\in \mathcal{P}_n}
P\otimes P\Big]
= \mathbb F \ ,
$$
where now the SWAP $\mathbb F$ acts on the entire $n$ qubits.
We thus have that
$$
\sum_{P\in \mathcal{P}_n}\Xi_P(|\psi\rangle)
=
\langle\psi\otimes\psi\rvert
\mathbb F
\lvert \psi\otimes\psi\rangle\ .
$$
Since we evaluate the SWAP on the tensor product $\lvert \psi\otimes\psi\rangle$, this is nothing but
$\langle \psi\vert \psi\rangle^2$, or equivalently $\mathrm{tr}\big(\lvert\psi\rangle\langle \psi\rvert\big)^2$.

If I understand it correctly, $\mathcal P_n$ forms a basis for Hermitian operators acting over the space of $n$ qubits. For example, if $n=1$, $\mathcal P_1 = \{\mathbb I,X,Y,Z\}$, and any state $\rho$ could be written as
$$
\rho = \frac 12(\mathbb I + r_xX+r_yY+r_zZ),
$$
Where $r_j$ are the tomograph coefficients, defined by
$$
r_x = \operatorname{Tr} (\rho X).
$$
And analogously for other directions. If $\rho$ is a pure state
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(\rho^2) = 1
$$
But in terms of the tomographic coefficients,
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(\rho^2) = \frac 12(1+ r_x^2 + r_y^2 + r_z^2 )= 1.
$$
The last equality is true, because the Pauli matrices satisfy $\operatorname{Tr}(P_i P_j) = 2\delta_{i,j}$. Now, you see that, for pure states
$$
\sum_{P\in \mathcal{P}_n}\Xi_P(|\psi\rangle)= \frac 12(1+ r_x^2 + r_y^2+r_z^2) \equiv \operatorname{Tr}(\rho^2)= 1
$$

It is not hard to check that for two qubits, $\mathcal P_2 = \{\mathbb I\otimes I, X\otimes \mathbb I,\dots,Z\otimes Z\}$. For any two elements of this group, we also have (you can check it) $\operatorname{Tr}(P_iP_j) = 4\delta_{ij}$. But this set is again the multi-qubit Pauli basis, so any state could be written as
$$
\rho = \frac 14 \sum_{P\in\mathcal P_2} r_p P
$$
And again, if the state is pure
$$
\operatorname{Tr} (\rho^2) = \frac 14 \sum_{P\in \mathcal P_2} r_p^2 = 1
$$
But again, this is exactly the entropy that you're trying to calculate.

It is not hard to generalize this arguments for $n$ qubits. The whole point is to notice that the multi-qubits Pauli matrices form a basis for the density matrices of multi qubit states, and this entropy is equivalent to purity of the state.
